# Creating php.ini file breaks magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, server, ini

I am experiencing a problem with my Magento website. I am trying to increase the memory limit which I have tried to do with the .htaccess and now I am trying with the php.ini file.

However, When I create a php.ini file i come up with this error on any page public or admin, magento comes up with a generic error 'there was an error processing your request'. There also doesn't seem to be anything in the log files.

The content of the php.ini file is below and I have tried it with just the part i need plus nothing else and any php.ini file just breaks it

Any help on why the php.ini file is breaking the site would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,
Matt

```
  ; This file is for CGI/FastCGI installations.
 ; Try copying it to php5.ini, if it doesn't work
; adjust memory limit

memory_limit = 128M

max_execution_time = 18000

; disable magic quotes for php request vars

magic_quotes_gpc = off

; disable automatic session start
; before autoload was initialized

flag session.auto_start = off

; enable resulting html compression

zlib.output_compression = on

; disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

suhosin.session.cryptua = off

; turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = off

; PHP for some reason ignores this setting in system php.ini 
; and disables mcrypt if this line is missing in local php.ini

extension=mcrypt.so

; Disable PHP errors, notices and warnings output in production mode to prevent exposing sensitive information.

display_errors = Off
```

Comment: You likely need to add to the existing php.ini file, not make a whole new one. Seems like you're possibly overriding the existing one with your new one.

Comment: Why you do not use ini_set('memory_limit', '128M'); in your script instead of creating a new php.ini file?